# What is the part called that connects the engine to the air intake system? (Photo included)

Tags: pontiac

The image below is from a 2003 Pontiac Sunfire.
Credits to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontiac_Sunfire) for the photo.

I've put arrows to the the part that I'd like to know what it's called.

I bought a used car and that part is missing.

Thanks

PS: Please feel free to update the post with more accurate information.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That is called the **Engine Crankcase Ventilation Hose** ... The part number is 24467120 and is #18 in this diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To add to Paul's answer - the crankcase ventilation hose is required in order to prevent fumes from the engine oil escaping to atmosphere - instead they are ventilated into the air intake, so they pass through the engine and are burnt with the fuel.